# How do I pass the values of the pop up modal to the original table

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

**Original form**

```
<table>
     for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
     {
      <tr>
      <td><input name="data[$i]"/> <button onclick="getElementById('modal').style.display('block')"> 
          </button></td>
      </tr>
     }
</table>
```

**The pop up modal**

```
<div id="modal">
         <table>
         <tr>
             <td>Value 1</td>
             <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         </table>
</div>
```

How do I get the td value from popup modal to the original form Table tr td upon click on that particular row?

Comment: you want to pass a current $row value to Bootstrap Modal??

Comment: sorry im a little bad at explaining, when user selects the row from the popup modal, the value should be passed back to the original form table's current$row.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add an `event` to the `<td>` tags.

`<td onclick="return sendValue(this);">Value 1</td>`

In the calling (parent) window add such JS code:

```
function HandlePopupEvent(result) {
    alert("the selected popup value: " + result);
}
```

In the child window(popup) code add this:

```
function sendValue(sender) {
    try {
        window.opener.HandlePopupResult(sender.innerHTML);
    }
    catch (err) {}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: please explain it with adding comments also.